# Could't load file or assembly after hosting WCF service on IIS

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I have searched all the related question which similar to my question in stack overflow. But I didn't find any useful information.
My question: I have one dll asume as xyz.dll in that dll one method is there which accepts 2 parameters x and y . Based on these parameters it will create object for some abc class. I have written a WCF service to call that method from xyz.dll. When I run the service as WCFServiceClient It worked well I got data (Meas I got abc class). Then I have hosted this service in my local IIS and I have created a WinForms Client application to consume this IIS Hosted WCF Service . But I am getting the following error.

> Could not load file or assembly 'file:///c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\xyz.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I have been trying for the solution for 3 days.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv let me think at an issue with Environment.CurrentDirectory, try to force it.

Comment: Which process gives that error? Your WCF service, or the client? Either way, make sure the required assembly is present in the application directory.

Comment: @CodeCaster, thanks for the reply. I have copied all the related files in concerned folders properly. As I explained above my service is working fine when it is run through F5(as WCFHostTestClient). But after hosting it on IIS server and after calling from a client I got this error.

Comment: Why it is checking in c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\ folder instead of checking in its Bin folder.